# Postgresql unique violation on primary key when inserting record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Rails 4.2 with Postgresql I got this error when trying to save a new ActiveRecord object

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: Duplicate Key Value Violates Unique Constraint 'My_table_name_pkey'

It looks like it's trying to insert the record into the table with a primary key that already exists. How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that somtimes the counter PG uses to generate primary keys can get messed up (I don't know how) and it justs needs to be reset to be the maximum value for the primary key in the table.

I found this answer in [Jasith Fernando's blog](http://blog.thekindof.me/blog/2013/12/05/fixing-pg-uniqueviolation-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint/)

For me this was happening in the development database so I went into a console for that db like this:

```
rails db development
```

Then the name of the variable that needs resetting is the name of the table appended with `_id_seq` so the command to reset it to the maximum primary key value is this

```
SELECT setval('my_table_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table));
```

Comment: What if this issue came in production?? I am getting this issue in production but only some times. Also the sequence of pkey is also correct. :(

Comment: If the issue comes in production then run the SELECT statement in the production database. It won't change any existing primary keys.

Comment: I am telling you that the sequence of pkey is correcty by running the select query in production database. Also I am getting uniqueness of primary key violation only some times. @Toby 1 Kenobi